# Try make «fixed» strokeWidth on scaling

Tags: fabricjs

Find some solution of «scaling strokeWidth problem» in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/av4hxjyr/), but it have some strange reposition effect

```
el.on({
'scaling': function(e) {
    var obj = this,
        w = obj.width * obj.scaleX,
        h = obj.height * obj.scaleY,
        s = obj.strokeWidth;

    obj.set({
        'height'     : h,
        'width'      : w,
        'scaleX'     : 1,
        'scaleY'     : 1
    });
}
});
```

anyway I think about draw rect like path and redraw on scaling. Any goof idea?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? And what is this "strange reposition effect" you're talking about?

Comment: Try move left border to right

Comment: ohhh i do not like that. needs a deep check in fabricjs.

Comment: guys from http://joxi.ru/?_locale=en fix what problem, but it too difficult way.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi, may be exist any way to prevent scaling and replace it to increase width/heigth with events? It must work only on objects with strokeWidth != 0.

Comment: is easier to prevent stroke to be deformed.

Comment: can you show where i can try to make it?